# How to retrieve the location of another android device?

Tags: android, geolocation

First of all I would like to mention that this would be done with the consent of all users!

That being said, what I am trying to create is an application where the users would see their location and the location of all the other connected users (latitude and longitude).

I am pretty sure the best way to do that would be to send data to a server and then have each device retrieve that data but I would like to know if there exist other ways of doing this. Or perhaps someone could point me in the right direction on how to create such a system with a server retrieving and sending data to android devices ?

Comment: GPS coordinates will do for you. You can get the coordinates and save in server then all the coordinates of a particular device can be retrieved by any connected device.

Comment: And I presume the java net package would do the job for that ?

Comment: We have Location and LocationManager in Android to do the job for you. Details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1513485/how-do-i-get-the-current-gps-location-programmatically-in-android

Comment: Adding it as answer, so that it helps other friends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GPS coordinates will do for you. You can get the coordinates and save in server then all the coordinates of a particular device can be retrieved by any connected device.

We have Location and LocationManager in android which shall do the job for you. Read more about these in the [Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html)